# Help with trigonometry right angle triangles problem!

Tags: trigonometry

Mount Kea is a dormant volcano on the island of Hawaii, and also the highest seamount in the world as measured from its base on the oceanic plate. At an unknown distance along with the oceanic plate from the peak of Mauna Kea, the angle of elevation to the peak is approximately $45.29^\circ$. Exactly $5000$ meters closer to the volcano, the angle of elevation to the volcano’s peak increases to approximately $63.66^\circ$. Using only the trigonometry of right-angle triangles and the given information, determine the height of Mount Kea's peak above the oceanic plate. At what distance from the peak would the second reported angle of elevation have been measured? Is using tangent the correct function to find the height? What exactly is the second part of the question asking for? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Max in respect to asking questions, it would be nice to know your thoughts on the problem as it will help people understand where you are facing difficulties.

Comment: Hi Rick. I have already found h by using tangent which is 10,100m but I don't quite understand the second part of the question.

Comment: Is it the hypotenuse of the second triangle that it is asking for?

Comment: No, it is asking for the distance between the second point and Mount Fuji. For that, you need to find the total distance between the two mountains (the base) and subtract from it the distance of the second point from mount Mauna Kea i.e. 5000 m.

Comment: Also, all of this works if we consider the mountains as straight lines (without any breadth).

Comment: Did u mean the second distance as the first distance is 5000m? So, I find the whole distance and then subtract 5000 to get the asking distance?

Comment: yeah that's it.

Comment: so I used tan45.29 = 10,100/tan45.29 = 9998 ( for the whole distance), then 9998 - 5000 = 4998m ( for the second distance ), is that correct? Should i just round it to 5000m? is it possible for both triangle to have the same distance?

Comment: Mauna Kea is in Hawaii, about 6600 km from Mount Fuji, and on a different plate. My guess is this problem was originally written using Mauna Kea as the mountain's name, but here the name was changed to Mount Fuji except in one place that the person who edited this problem overlooked.

Comment: Where did you get 10,100? I don't see that anywhere in the question. Is it your solution for the height of the seamount? This is where showing your work would help people understand what you need to know.

Comment: As further evidence that this question was originally about Mauna Kea and not about Mount Fuji at all, the question doesn't even really make sense for Mount Fuji (whose "height above the sea floor" is not easy to look up, probably because it's not a relevant fact), whereas it makes perfect sense for Mauna Kea (whose approximate height above the sea floor you can easily look up).

Answer (score 0):

Now since you have edited the question it is much easier to answer.

Let $H$ be the height of Mauna Kea from the base of the oceanic plate. Let d be the base distance between the base and first point of observation on the oceanic plate. Now from the question,

From the first point angle of elevation of  Mauna Kea = $45.29 ^{\circ}$

This means $\tan (45.29^{\circ}) = \frac{H}{d}$ using definition of $\tan$.

Also when we move $5000\ m$ towards Mauna Kea on the plate, angle of elevation becomes = $63.66^{\circ}$

This implies that $\tan(63.66^{\circ}) = \frac{H}{d-5000}$

Equating value of $H$ from the above two equations, we get $$d \tan(45.29^{\circ}) =  (d-5000)\tan(63.66^{\circ}) \Rightarrow d = \frac{5000 \tan(63.66^{\circ})}{\tan(63.66^{\circ})-\tan(45.29^{\circ})} \approx 10002.7434$$

So the distance of the second point from the base of the volcano is $d-5000  = 50002.7434$

The height of volcano = $H = d\tan(45.29^{\circ})= 10104.5163.$

Notice that this makes sense as the angle of elevation from the first point is $45.29^{\circ}$, so the height and base must be almost equal as $\tan(45^{\circ}) = 1$ and our angle is only a bit more than that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Mauna Kea is in Hawaii. I think there is only supposed to be one mountain in the question, so instead of $H-h$ we just have $H.$ Otherwise we'd have two equations with three unknowns.

Comment: Note that from the setup of the variables here, we should have $d > 5000.$

Comment: I agree with your calculation of $d$ now. If you then plug that value of $d$ into each of the other formulas, they each give the same value of $H-h$ ... and that's as far as we can go. If you draw a diagram of your interpretation of the question then it should be clear that there is only information about the change in elevation from one peak to the other, and non about the distance to the ocean floor.

Comment: Yeah I see that

Comment: As I commented under the question, I think the problem itself is fundamentally broken due to someone poorly editing an older problem. It puts all of us at a huge disadvantage in trying to figure out what was meant.

Comment: Yeah, I agree to that now, I was a bit hasty. But given the height of one of the peaks we can solve for other's if there are two peaks. Else if there is only one peak, then we can directly get the height after computing the distance from point of observations.

Comment: Sorry guys. I read the question wrong. There is only one mountain which is Mount Kea. Yes, 10,100m is the height of Mount Kea and I got the answer by using tangent. For the second half of the question, I used tangent again with the angle of 45.29 to find the whole distance for both elevations. Tan45.29 = 10,100/d = 10100/tan45.29 = 9998.27. Then subtract 5000 to get 4998m. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes, that is it, I have edited the answer, you may check for it.

Comment: Hi Rick, how come I got 4998m? and yrs is 10002m?

Comment: I used $d$ for the total distance (from B to C in the diagram in the answer below), you got it $9998.27$ and not $4998$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From the diagram,

$$ 5000 = BC - BD = h \cot (45.29^\circ) - h\cot (63.66^\circ) $$

Thus, the height $h$ is,

$$ h = \frac{5000}{\cot 45.29^\circ -\cot 63.66^\circ} = 10105 \space \text{m}$$

The distance from the peak for the second elevation measurement is

$$ BD = 10105\times \cot(63.66^\circ) = 5003 \space \text{m} $$

Comment: Thanks for the diagram. It will help O.P. much better. P.S. I don't know how to put a diagram.

Comment: Hi Rick, it is definitely not asking for the distance of AD? It says the distance from the peak of the second elevation?

Comment: @MaxHong I can assure you that the answers given by me and Quanto are correct to what is the most simple interpretation of your question.

Comment: and where did anyone find $AD$?

Comment: by using the distance formula AD = squareroot of AB^2 + BD^2? I just thought I would double check. I am sure you are both right. I will stick with that. Thank you.

Comment: @MaxHong consider accepting an answer so that the question might be closed.